# Program crashes when accessing first element of vector

Tags: c++, vector, crash

I'm currently trying to solve a problem, where an access to the first element of a vector crashes my application.

This is only a demonstrational recreation of the code, not the actual code.

```
class Group
{
    public:
    Player* get_first_player();

    private:
    std::vector<Player*> players;
}
```

And this is the implementation of the class:

```
Player* Group::get_first_player()
{
    if (players.size() > 0)
        return players[0];
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

And this is a calling demo:

```
Player* p = myGroup->get_first_player();
if (p != nullptr)
    ...
```

Now the actual problem: The program crashes on the line "return players[0]". But it doesn't crash always when executing this line, only after my application ran all day long (sometimes it crashes after 4h, sometimes after 10h).
I could imagine two things: Either the vector is somehow corrupt, or the group object on which I do the call is invalid. But if it's the latter, why doesn't the players.size() fail before it can get to the return players[0]?

If someone is interested in it, here is the actual code generated by the compiler and disassembled with IDA:

```
  v7 = *(_DWORD *)myGroup;
  if ( (*(_DWORD *)(myGroup + 4) - *(_DWORD *)myGroup) >> 2 )
    ret = *(_DWORD *)v7;
  else
    ret = 0;
```

Comment: This is almost impossible to diagnose without seeing the whole picture. Memory corruption might be the cause.

Comment: "This is impossible to diagnose without seeing the whole picture. Memory corruption might be the cause." fixed. I bet `myGroup` is not valid, * fly away *

Comment: But when `myGroup` is invalid, why does the .size() call succeed? Aka. when looking at the disassembled code, why can `myGroup+4` get dereferenced without problems and `**myGroup` fails?

Comment: because undefined behavior is undefined behavior give a [mcve] !

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the vector becomes invalid at some point but there's no enough info to tell why. Could you debug with GDB or something?

Comment: @jjimenezg93 It's a server software and the bug seems to appear randomly. I can't debug it because I don't know when the bug will happen again (or whatever it is that makes the vector corrupt). But I'm almost 100% sure that the group object itself does exist and is valid.

Comment: Please post all the code needed to produce the error as a complete example.